# How do i sent arguement to pandas.style.apply in pandas to apply highlighting to cell

Tags: python, pandas, styles, apply

I am trying to highlight the difference between two worksheets column. I have gotten two boolean series mask(mask1, mask2) to tell whether there is any difference between two columns Quantity and Booked in two dataframe df_A and df_B

I want to highlight the difference so I passed in this manner

```
def highlight_changes(df, m1, m2):
     y= 'yellow'
     df1 = pd.DataFrame('background-color: {}'.format(''), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
    # rewrite values by boolean masks
     df1['Quantity'] = np.where(m1, 'background-color: {}'.format(y), df1['Quantity'])
     df1['Booked'] = np.where(m2, 'background-color: {}'.format(y), df1['Booked']

     return df1

### mask1 and mask2 derived previously
df_n.style.apply(highlight_changes, args=(mask1, mask2), axis=None).to_excel('writer.xlsx')
```

On running, it gives me the error:

```
TypeError: highlight_changes() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args'
```

I guess it means that pandas.style.apply method does not have arguements in it

I tried to use lambda function but I am not too sure how to pass external apply lambda function. I could think of is by appending mask1 and mask2 to df_n and then run this

```
df_n.style.apply(lambda x: highlight_changes(x,mask1, mask2), axis=None).to_excel('writer.xlsx')
```

However I do not want mask1 & mask2 to appear part of the excel spreadsheet

How could I do this?

Thanks

---

**UPDATE**

df_o

S/N     Pe      Date        Material    Batch   Quantity    Booked

3733    41116   20120726    25-22923-2  QM0200258   1   0

3734    41116   20120326    55-11943-2  SJ0030219   1   0

3735    41116   20120716    23-21963-2  PM1000210   1   0

4843    41589   20131111    1553        2215564     1   1

6861    41589   20131111    6147-1     2215565     1    1

(thats the old dataframe)

Previous dataframe df_o previous dataframe

[image]

Current Dataframe df_n new dataframe
[image]

Basically, I want to detect the changes in Quantity and Booked columns in the new dataframe.

---

I have gotten mask of the changes for Quantity and Booked column for df_n (not part of the dataframe)

mask1

[image]

mask2 looks similar with the same length

**Update**

Actual value of mask1 is False, True, False   (Aaccordig to sample)

Actual value of mask2 is True, False, False   (Aaccordig to sample)

---

Now what I want to do is highlight the changes in df_n

[image]

What I have done
One of the solution I could think is to merge the mask1 & 2 into df_n but i do not want mask1 and mask2... but i have problems in dropping them off in highlight_changes function.

I tried chaining the drop function after apply highlight_changes but it is a style object not dataframe.

Comment: Can you post your sample dataframe/worksheet and expected output?

Comment: 1. do `print(df_o)` and copy/paste the text here, not the picture. 2. What do `m1`, `m2` look like? 3. how do you want the `df_n` to be?

Comment: Does `df_n` and `df_o` have the same length? or does `df_n` have the same length with `m1` and `m2`?

Comment: @Quang Hoang:   Originally df_n and df_o does not have the same length, I have merged both of them together and gotten the mask (that detect the differences in df_n ie m1 and m2 ). For records that exist in df_o but does not exist in df_n, I do not have to bother... and df_n and df_o has common key in S/N columns

Answer (score 0):

I think I mite have a workaround to dropping redundant columns and rename my columns: is to modify the codes at the to_excel end

1. First I merge my dataframe df_o and df_n based on column S/N
2. Next i will call the function below

   df_on.style.apply(lambda x: highlight_changes(x,mask1, mask2), axis=None).to_excel('writer.xlsx', columns =colsyouwant, header=headernameyouwant)
3. In the function, I will process and obtain the mask i need to selectivelycolour my two columns
4. Next I will use the mask to colour the cell i need
5. Finally I will remove the unneeded columns and rename the needed column
6. save it